# MongoDB - $search throwing an unknown error occurred in mongo Atlas

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, full-text-search, atlas

I am using mongo Atlas to use $search aggregation pipeline stage. I know that the $search aggregation pipeline stage is only available for collections hosted on MongoDB Atlas cluster and I have proper subscription so that's not the problem. I am trying to write a $search stage with autocomplete operator. When I type the word I want to show all the matching values as result.

```
[
    {
        '$search': {
            'index': 'Custom_Test', 
            'autocomplete': {
                'path': 'SomeFileName', 
                'query': 'Test', 
                'tokenOrder': 'sequential'
            }, 
            'highlight': {
                'path': [
                    'SomeFileName'
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 10
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1, 
            'SomeFileName': '$SomeFileName', 
            'Ancestors': 1, 
            'highlights': {
                '$meta': 'searchHighlights'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

So when I am passing Test it should return all the matching SomeFileName fields. I tried to remove index as well because it will pick up default if not mentioned and tried it but no use. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that the $search aggregation pipeline stage is only available for collections hosted on MongoDB Atlas.

This is not accurate, atlas search is a separate feature "unrelated" to the base Mongodb product. It is built using the lucene engine similarly to many modern text search engines.

This means it's actually maintaining a separate inverse index database to allow such text search capabilities. This also means the data needs to be prepared and tokenised accordingly - there is no magic search layer that can achieve such performance without preprocessing.

You need to create a new collection as a search index, define proper mapping and tokenizing methods and insert the data there for it to be prepared. This is actually quite simple, just follow [their docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/create-index/) on how to do this.

final disclaimer this answer has some inaccuracies as I decided to simplify the explanation.

Comment: Thank you, as a matter of fact I had tired to create a search index and it started to work, as per the documentation I have read, it was mentioned that if no index is mentioned it will take default index. So I was assuming that even if I don't create a search index it should work. As you said it maintains a separate index database.

Comment: Okay but is this feature possible to be used from a self hosted instance? And if not is there an alternative for self hosted mongodb databases?

Comment: No, it's essentially a completely new db they built and integrated into the existing product.